# css vertical align button inside span dynamic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this situation [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m1fnx2q1/10/) , When resizing window vertically I want to be able to have spans act like harmonica (I have this working). Unfortunately I can't get buttons inside spans to align vertically in the middle, they are always align to top in span. I tried everything.

Thx.

```
<div id="color-list">
            <span class="vertical-tool"><button id="black-color" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>
                    <span class="vertical-tool"><button id="blue-color" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>
                    <span class="vertical-tool"><button id="yellow-color" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>
                    <span class="vertical-tool"><button id="orange-color" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>
                    <span class="vertical-tool"><button id="red-color" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>
                    <span class="vertical-tool"><button id="green-color" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>
                    <span class="vertical-tool"><button id="clear-writing-button" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>
                    <span class="vertical-tool"><button id="clear-page-button" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just need to add another HTML element inside your "verticle-tool" `Span` tag that to capitalize on the `display: table-cell` property.

**CSS**

```
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="color-list">
    <span class="vertical-tool">
        <span class="cell"><button id="black-color" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>
    </span>
    <span class="vertical-tool">
        <span class="cell"><button id="blue-color" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>
    </span>
    <span class="vertical-tool">
        <span class="cell"><button id="yellow-color" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>
    </span>
    <span class="vertical-tool">
        <span class="cell"><button id="orange-color" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>
    </span>
    <span class="vertical-tool">
        <span class="cell"><button id="red-color" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>
    </span>
    <span class="vertical-tool">
        <span class="cell"><button id="green-color" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>
    </span>
    <span class="vertical-tool">
        <span class="cell"><button id="clear-writing-button" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>
    </span>
    <span class="vertical-tool">
        <span class="cell"><button id="clear-page-button" class="vertical-icon"></button></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

[See your updated Js.Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/m1fnx2q1/12/)

Comment: Thank you. Great. I wish you all the best in the new year.